# What is the asymptotic form for the sum of the reciprocals of the first $n$ primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

It is well known that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes $p$ less than or equal to a maximum value $n$ is asymptotic to $\ln \ln n$:
$$\sum_{p \leq n} \frac{1}{p} \sim \ln \ln n.$$
(The next subleading term on the RHS is the [Meissel–Mertens constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant).)

But what's the asymptotic form for the sum of the reciprocals of the first $k$ primes? That is, if $p_k = \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, \dots\}$ is the sequence of primes, then what is the asymptotic form of
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k}?$$
The latter expression seems to me to be a closer variant of the famous asymptotic relation
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \sim \ln n$$
for the harmonic numbers.

Comment: well, $p_n \approx n \log n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $\frac{m \log m}{2} \le p_m \le 2 m \log m$. So $\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{p_k}$ satisfies

$$\ln \ln (m \log m/2) \approx \sum_{p \le \frac{m \log m}{2}} \frac{1}{p} \le \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{p_k} \le
\sum_{p \le 2m \log m} \frac{1}{p} \approx \ln \ln (2m \log m )$$.

However, $\ln \ln (m \log m/2)$ $\approx \ln \ln m \approx$ $\ln \ln (2m \log m )$, yielding

$$\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{p_k} \approx \ln \ln m.$$

And it makes sense: From analysis (forget about primes and their distributions for a moment)

$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k \ln k} \approx \ln \ln N$ (and $p_k \approx k \ln k$); $\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k \ln k \ln \ln k} \approx \ln \ln \ln N$  while $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k \ln^2 k}$ is finite. In fact, so is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k (\ln k) (\ln \ln k)^2}$. And even, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k (\ln k) (\ln \ln k) (\ln \ln \ln k)^2}$ is finite too.

If this is still surprising to you, let $Y(x) = e^{e^x}$, then $dY/dx = Y \ln Y$. And let $Z = e^{e^{e^x}}$. Then $dZ/dx = Z \ln Z \ln \ln Z$.

Comment: The Prime Number Theorem $\pi (x)\sim x/\ln x $ ( where $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes less than $x$ ) immediately gives $p_n\sim n \ln p_n, $ and with a little elementatary work on that, we get $p_n\sim n\ln n$..... So $\sum_{j=1}^n1/p_j\sim$ $ \sum_{j=1}^n/(j\ln j)\sim$ $ \int_2^n(1/x\ln x)dx=$ $\int_{x=2}^n(1/\ln x)d(\ln x)\sim$ $\ln \ln n.$

Comment: Just to say Chebyshev bound $\frac{p_n}{n\ln n} \in (a,b)$ is quite the same as $\frac{1}{ \ln \ln n}\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} \in  (a,b)$. To obtain Mertens theorem you'll also need that $\lim_{s \to 1}\int_2^\infty (\pi(x)-\frac{x}{\ln x}) x^{-s-1}dx = C$ so that $\sum_{p \ge x} \frac{1}{p\ln p}\sim \sum_{n \ge x} \frac{1}{n\ln^2 n}$